# How to Create a back ground system service in Android Q

Tags: android-10.0, selinux, system-services

I am trying to create a System service which runs once system boots up, I have followed required steps except sepolicy files update.
I have referred https://android.jlelse.eu/system-service-in-aosp-750007d39555.
Currently My service is not running as avc denied error is coming. I am running in permissive mode. I have tried to add required changes in service.te and conexts.te in /system/sepolicy/public/service.te. I am getting compilation error as [6:49 PM] Kumar, Rathnakaram Anil (uic40644)

[4:03 PM] Kumar, Rathnakaram Anil (uic40644)

Hi Ashwini,
I am trying to add selinux permissions for my test service, facing error:
[ 13% 18579/140712] build out/target/product/caaf_denali_pegasus/obj/ETC/sepolicy_freeze_test_intermediates/sepolicy_freeze_test FAILED: out/target/product/caaf_denali_pegasus/obj/ETC/sepolicy_freeze_test_intermediates/sepolicy_freeze_test /bin/bash -c "(diff -rq -x bug_map system/sepolicy/prebuilts/api/29.0/public system/sepolicy/public ) && (diff -rq -x bug_map system/sepolicy/prebuilts/api/29.0/private system/sepolicy/private ) && (touch out/target/product/caaf_denali_pegasus/obj/ETC/sepolicy_freeze_test_intermediates/sepolicy_freeze_test )" Files system/sepolicy/prebuilts/api/29.0/private/service.te and system/sepolicy/private/service.te differ Files system/sepolicy/prebuilts/api/29.0/private/service_contexts and system/sepolicy/private/service_contexts differ.

I am not able to find any clue on how to update sepolicy for a new service, please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Edit the file /system/sepolicy/private/service_contexts and add this line

> service_name                                     u:object_r:service_name:s0

Recompile AOSP.

Comment: If the answer works for you, do select as accepted please :)

Answer (score 0):

1. Give your binary file a selable, add it to "file_contexts"

> /vendor/bin/xxx           u:object_r:xxx_exec:s0

2. Create a te file "xxx.te"

> ```
> # xxx service
> type xxx, domain;
> type xxx_exec, exec_type, vendor_file_type, file_type;
>
> init_daemon_domain(xxx)
> ```